# Gitlab not responding on local network unless I'm ssh'ed in

Tags: macos, nginx, ssh, gitlab, unicorn

After installing Gitlab on my Mac OS X El Capitan (following [this guide](https://github.com/WebEntity/Installation-guide-for-GitLab-on-OS-X)), I've noticed that the server runs fine on localhost, but does not respond when I try to access it from another computer on the network (192.168.1.xxx). However, if I SSH into the Mac OS X machine containing Gitlab and THEN try to access the server while the SSH connection is open, the server responds normally and I'm able to access the server.

My initial thought was that it could be a(n) nginx issue, but I haven't found anything helpful in the logs thus far (although I'm not sure what to be looking for, either).

Comment: encrypted home?

Comment: @Jakuje no, it's not encrypted

Comment: When you try to access gitlab from another host and it's not responding, what actual behavior do you see and what specific errors do you get?